# Get substring between strings. But the start occurs multiple times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If I have the following string:

```
s = 'sdsdsdBetreft:ddddddBetreft:HOOOIIIIgagaga'
```

How do I get the `HOOOIIII`?

I tried the following:

```
p = re.search(r'Betreft:(.*?)gagaga', s).group(1)
print(p)
```

But that gives me:

```
ddddddBetreft:HOOOIIII
```

This is because 'Betreft' occurs multiple times. I'm lost.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm also lost.  What is the logic by which `HOOOIIII` gets targeted within your larger string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry if I confused you. But the logic is that I know I need everthing that is between Betreft: and gagaga. Which is HOOOIIII in this case

Comment: Well...technically your current code is already doing this.  How do we know to target the second `Betreft` ?

Comment: That's my point. I have no idea

Comment: Maybe there is something to tell the regex to look where Betreft and gagaga are the closest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is that expressions like `.*` usually match
**too much** text, compared to the actual intention of the regex author.

One of possible solutions is to match a sequence of chars **other than `:`**,
and probably a better choice is the **non-empty** variant, so the central
part of the regex shoud be: `[^:]+`.

As you defined "border strings" (before and after the matched text),
use both of them as *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead*,
so the whole regex can be:

```
(?<=Betreft:)[^:]+(?=gagaga)
```

Comment: What does [^:]+ do exactly?

Comment: It means: A sequence of chars other than ":". "+" means "1 or more". Note that you put ".*?" in your regex, where "*" means "0 or more", so also the **empty** text will be matched. Do you really accept empty string?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you don't capture anything before the last `Betreft`, then one option is use lookarounds.  Consider the following *tempered* dot:

```
(?:(?!Betreft:).)*
```

This says to consume anything, so long as we never lookahead and see the string `Betreft`.  In the context of the pattern below, this is one way to avoid beginning the match at an earlier occurrence of `Betreft`.

```
s = 'sdsdsdBetreft:ddddddBetreft:HOOOIIIIgagaga'
p = re.search(r'(?<=Betreft:)(?:(?!Betreft:).)*(?=gagaga)', s).group(0)
print(p)

HOOOIIII
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.*` in front of your regex to consume all the preceding occurrences of `Betreft:`:

```
re.search(r'.*Betreft:(.*?)gagaga', s).group(1)
```

This returns: `HOOOIIII`

Comment: You probably want to use lazy dot `(.*?)` here, in case `gagaga` could occur more than once.

Comment: Indeed. Edited as suggested then.